# WebStorm not running project, Command `start` unrecognized

Tags: javascript, react-native, webstorm

I'm very new to React Native, barely two weeks into it. I've  installed node.js (ver 10.15.0), I've also installed yarn and downloaded WebStorm.

The problem is that I can't run a simple project created by WebStorm, it throws an error

> Command start unrecognized. Make sure that you have run npm install and that you are inside a react-native project.

I've `cd` into my WebStorm projects folder and run `npm install` in command prompt countless times but it's still throwing the error. Some online suggestions said I should set my path correctly, but I don't really know how to go about it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: show your `package.json file` , in it under scripts is start mentioned

Comment: Yea start is mentioned something like `{"start":"node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"}}`

Comment: does `npm install` succeed? Do you see any errors when running it?

Comment: Yea it installs successfully... After installation it says its up to date

Comment: whats your OS @eCuzzy

Comment: I'm on Windows 8.1

Comment: Is there any other way I can make the installations without using cmd?

Answer (score 0):

You should know The best IDE for react native is VSCode (visual studio code) and don't create project with IDE (you should use commands for create project. just use IDE for manage codes)

use CMD or PowerShell (Recommended) for commands

Create a folder for your project and in the project directory run this commands :

`npm install -g expo-cli`

`expo init Yourprojectname`

`cd Yourprojectname`

`npm start`

For run android project

`react-native run-android`

For run android project

`react-native run-ios`

Also its better to read this tutorial : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Comment: Thanks for the info. But running `npm install -g expo-cli` gives me some errors. `npm ERR! code E404 npm ERR! 404 Not Found: expo-cli@latest npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C://Users...`

Comment: skip this step and see what will happend

Comment: Ok, I ran `expo init Myproject`. It asked me to choose a template. I chose blank. `Yarn v1.12.3 found. Use Yarn to install dependencies?` I chose Yes. `Extracting project files...` `Customizing project...` `Installing dependencies...` `yarn install v1.12.3` `info No lockfile found.` `[1/4] Resolving packages...` `error Couldn't find package "expo" on the "npm" registry."` 
 `info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for doccumentation about this command` `info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...`

Comment: Then I ran it again without using yarn, after installing dependencies, it said `npm  ERR! code E404`   `npm ERR! 404 Not Found react@16.5.0`    `npm ERR! A complete log of this run canbe found in C://Users...`